# How to handle DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

If a `Bluetooth` server has a notifying characteristic and the remote client writes to the descriptor of this characteristic the value `DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE` , then how must the server cope with this descriptor write request?

Must the server software refrain from calling any `GattServer.notifyCharacteristicChanged()` , or will the `Bluetooth` stack prevent sending notifications to the client after `GattServer.notifyCharacteristicChanged()` has been called by the server software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server should only send a notification over the air if the corresponding notification bit in the descriptor is 1. Whether the application software is the one that should do this check or the bluetooth stack does this for you is implementation-specific. I guess most bluetooth stacks do *not* do this for you.

If you wonder about Android, I can't see clear documentation whether this is done or not, so you'd better do it yourself.